# Understanding DrawFeature and other events in the same time in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, events

Scenario 1:

Let's say I have something like this:

```
`app_obj.MapObj.map.events.register("click", app_obj.MapObj.map, self.pointToVideoSearch);`
```

and another Click Control

```
OpenLayers.Control.Click = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Control, {
        defaultHandlerOptions: {
            "single" : true,
            "double" : false,
            "pixelTolerance" : 0,
            "stopSingle" : true,
            "stopDouble" : false
        },
        initialize: function(options){
            this.handlerOptions = OpenLayers.Util.extend(
                {}, this.defaultHandlerOptions
                );
            OpenLayers.Control.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
            this.handler = new OpenLayers.Handler.Click(
                this, {
                    "click" : this.onClick,
                    "dblclick": this.onDblclick
                }, this.handlerOptions
            );
        },

        onClick: clickFunction,
        onDblclick: dblClickFunction
    });
```

When I click on the map, first and second control (it's activated) are fired up. Why the "clickStop" is not working and stoping other click events to be fired?

Scenario 2:

if I had event like in Scenario 1:

```
app_obj.MapObj.map.events.register("click", app_obj.MapObj.map, self.pointToVideoSearch);
```

and a DrawFeature control to draw let's say Polygon, then the first event is silenced (when I am drawing polygon), never fires up until you are not finished with drawing polygon

My question is, what is stoping first event to fire up? I need to find out that tehnic

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
controls = { 

    point:   new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(vectors, OpenLayers.Handler.Point, {
        eventListeners: {"featureadded": newPolygonAdded}
    }),

    line:    new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(vectors, OpenLayers.Handler.Path, {
        eventListeners: {"featureadded": newPolygonAdded}
    }),

    polygon: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(vectors, OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon, {
        eventListeners: {"featureadded": newPolygonAdded}
    }),

    regular: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(vectors, OpenLayers.Handler.RegularPolygon, {
        eventListeners: {"featureadded": newPolygonAdded },
        handlerOptions: {sides: 5}
    }),

    modify:  new OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature(vectors, {
        onModificationStart: startModify,
        onModification: doModify
    })
};

for (var key in controls)
{
    map.addControl(controls[key]);
}
```

And add the corresponding event functions.